# sudo rejects password that is correct

Tags: linux, sudo, arch-linux, su

sudo (Which I have configured to ask for a password) is rejecting my password (as if I mis-typed it)  I am absolutely not typing it incorrectly.  I have changed the password temporarily to alphabetic characters only, and it looks fine in plaintext, in the same terminal.  I have my username configured thus:

```
myusername ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I am using my password, NOT the root password, which are distinct.  Just to be sure, I've tried both (even though I know the root password is not what I should use)  - neither work.

I have added myself to the group 'wheel' additionally, and included the following line:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I'm kind of at the end of my rope here.  I don't know what would cause it to act as though it was accepting my password, but then reject it.  I have no trouble logging in with the same password, either at terminal shells, or through the X11 login manager.

Comment: sudo would generate a log message, perhaps in `/var/log/secure` (I don't know how syslog is configured in arch), explaining what it found wrong.

Comment: Do you have a `sudoers` entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? (it could be configured to look up the user incorrectly)

Comment: also the output of `sudo -l` could help, in arch the sudo log messages go to `/var/log/auth.log`

Answer (score 26):

Another possible cause is that systemd-homed is not running. Check it's status with

```
systemctl status systemd-homed
```

If it says something other than active, use

```
systemctl start systemd-homed
```

to start it again. Note that you need superuser privileges in order to run that command. As sudo is not working, you might try logging as root using

```
su root
```

and the correct password for root (usually not your regular user).

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this? On my systems, systemd-homed isn't running, and sudo works fine.

Comment: Of course. On my system, `systemd-homed` wasn't running as well. Out of a sudden, all attempts to use `sudo` with the correct password failed. `su root` with `root`'s password failed as well. So I checked the systemd journal and found an error message that said, `/home/<user>` was not a valid home directory, as `systemd-homed` was not running. Starting it manually fixed the issue temporarily, so I could at least reboot the machine using super user rights. Since then, the issue only occured sporadically, but not very often.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this -- it seems the default PAM configuration that comes with Arch Linux has a hard dependency on it running, but if you have an older installation and didn't update the PAM configs, obviously that doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.

Comment: This is a great suggestion if you’re using systemd-homed, but useless if you’re not.

Answer (score 7):

Oh what the heck, here was the issue, I guess?

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142720

```
pacman -S pambase
```

fixes it.

Comment: Not working for me